# Firestore create document with fields at root with REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to make an API call to create a document inside of my “Users” collection and include an “Age” and “Name” as fields. Unfortunately when I make the API call I create Users>document>collection>document>info I would like to omit: Users>document><s>collection>document></s>info but the API won’t let me.
Refer to the image below.
[image]

Currently my code looks like this:

```
POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users/hello/APITest HTTP/1.1

Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "fields": {
    "Name": {
      "stringValue": "Josh"
    },
    "Age": {
      "integerValue": "23"
    }
  }
}
```

I have removed some portions.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your current target URL:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users/hello/APITest
```

You are trying to write data to `/Users/hello/APITest`, which is the path of a collection, not a document. Because you haven't provided a document ID, Firestore generates one for you and creates a new document in that collection at:

```
/Users/hello/APITest/{automaticDocumentId}
```

To prevent this you need to change your path to that of a document, such as `/Users/hello`, which makes your target URL:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users/hello
```

Alternatively, you can let Firestore generate an ID for you by using just `/Users` and the target URL:

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users
```

Answer (score 0):

The http POST request path consists of two required path parameters one is `parent` and another is `collectionId`. In your case the http POST request is using the second type `parent` path parameter which is mentioned in the `OR` section of the parent path parameter [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument#path-parameters) i.e.

```
projects/{project_id}/databases/{databaseId}/documents/chatrooms/{chatroom_id}.
```

So in your case the `parent` path parameter is : `projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users/hello` and `APITest` is the `collectionId`. Therefore Firestore is creating a nested collection i.e. a collection `Users` within which a document `hello` and within that another collection `APITest` and within that a document having an auto generated document id.

So to have the field values in the root document you have to specify the `parent` path parameter as : `projects/{project_id}/databases/{databaseId}/documents` and the `collectionId` path parameter as `Users`. It will create a collection with `collectionId` `Users` and within that a document with an auto generated document id.

So in your case the http post request will look like the following -

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users
```

Please note that if you try to use `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users/hello` it will throw an invalid argument error as the path parameters mentioned here are not meeting the Firestore http POST request path parameters requirement as mentioned in the above referred document.

Instead if you want to use your custom document id you can use the query parameter as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument#query-parameters). So your http request will look like following -

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/###/databases/(default)/documents/Users/?documentId=custom_document_id
```