# How can I add a collection to a document in Firestore coding?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, collections, document

I have an app where when the user sign up, I create a collection in my db with Firestore using this function.

```
const createUser = async ( collection , data ) => {
    //adding data to a collection with automatic id
     )
    await setDoc( 
      doc( firestore, collection, data.id) , data )
      
    //console.log( ref.id )
  }
```

So when the user signup I create a collection with an auto generated id by doing this:

```
const SignupHandler = ( email, password, username ) => {
    setSignupError(null)
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword( FBauth, email, password )
    .then( ( userCredential ) => { 
      createUser('users', {id: userCredential.user.uid, email:userCredential.user.email, displayName:username})
      console.log(username)
      console.log(userCredential)
      setUser(userCredential)
      setAuth( true )
    } )
    .catch( (error) => { setSignupError(error.code) })
  }
```

Now I want to create a document inside the user call "tasks" and add an auto id, a name and a date. How do I do that, I have looking around and can't find the solution. The structure of the db would be
Collection users-document user(userid name and mail)-collection "tasks"-task document(id name and date)

Answer (score 0):

A collection is created automatically when you add the first document to it.

If you want to specify the document ID, then you'll need to do this,

```
db.collection('users').doc(user).collection(‘tasks’).doc(task).set({ id : this.id, name : this.name, date : this.date})
```

If you want to let Cloud Firestore auto-generate an ID for you. You can do this by calling add():

```
db.collection('users').doc(user).collection(‘tasks’).add({id: this.id, name: this.name, date: this.date })
```

This page details how to [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

You can also make REST API calls to create a path to a document with the ID in the collection under the project YOUR_PROJECT_ID . For that you would use the following structure :

```
/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA
```

To interact with this path, combine it with the base API URL for creating a path to a document with ID LA and collection name ‘cities’
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA

For creating Firestore nested collections, you can also use HTTP POST requests like mentioned in this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument). To understand the process  in detail on how we can add collections and documents by specifying path parameters parent and collectionID follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69584795/15803365).